# Twice-interrupted circular path in SVG

Tags: svg

I want to create a circular path with multiple "Holes" in it, preferably without using masks and the like.

Currently, what I've got is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/umy5v421/):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <path d="M 100 100 A 90 90 0 1 0 200 100 M 110 90 A 90 90 0 0 1 190 90" stroke="#424242" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

As you can see, this relies on manually moving the start of the new arc, which results in the arc being off.

I'd rather not have to do a lot of math to get the position for the move *just right*, so is there a sort of "Arc move" I can use?

If not, how does the math for this work (I'm very rusty in geometry stuff)

Comment: As it stands, your question is practically unanswerable. What are you trying to achieve exactly? How many of these holes do you need? Do they move independently? Are they always the same size? Do they need to be animated? Can't you just cover up the unwanted parts of the circle with objects painted the same colour as the background? How are you generating the data that describes where the holes should be? If you're doing this calculation in Javascript, why can't you use a library like d3.js to create the drawings? (Also, calculating one sine and one cosine is hardly "a lot of math".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is probably just to use a dash array.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <path d="M 100 100 A 90 90 0 1 0 200 100 M 110 90 A 90 90 0 0 1 190 90" stroke="#424242" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" />
    <path d="M 60 175 A 90 90 0 0 1 240 175 A 90 90 0 0 1 60 175" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="88 14 78 14 372"/></svg>
```